# Can we isloate inside If function

Tags: r, shiny

In the below application, when we select second element in the Group By filter (Say Country), a render UI is popped up with default as 'USA'. When the user selects second country (sat UK) and selects Gender in the Group By filter, the second filter now becomes only USA (not USA and UK) . Wanted to check if we can still keep USA and UK in the second filter?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("groupby", "Group By", choices = c("Month","Country","Gender", "Site ID", "Treatment Arm"),multiple = TRUE,selected = c("Month")),
  uiOutput("coun")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if(length(input$groupby) > 1){
      output$coun <- renderUI({selectInput("country", "Country",selected = "USA", choices = c("USA","UK","EUR"),multiple = TRUE)})
    } else {
      output$coun <- renderUI({})
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Warning: Error in force: objet 'raw_data' introuvable

Comment: Try to use mtcars or iris sample datasets to make your reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing `observe` and `renderUI`.  `renderXXXX` should never appear inside a reactive.

It would have been helpful to have your `raw_data`.

I think this does what you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Create some raw data
raw_data <- tibble(Country=c("USA", "GB", "France"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "groupby", 
    "Group By", 
    choices = c("Month","Country","Gender", "Site ID", "Treatment Arm"),
    multiple = TRUE,
    selected = c("Month")
  ),
  uiOutput("coun")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Make a note of the "currently" selected countries
  v <- reactiveValues(selectedCountries=c(raw_data$Country[1]))
  
  output$coun <- renderUI({
    # Respond to changes in the groupby input
     if ("Country" %in% input$groupby) {
      selectInput(
        "country",
        "Country",
        selected = v$selectedCountries,
        choices = as.character(raw_data$Country),
        multiple = TRUE
      )
     } else {
      ""
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$country, {
    # Respond to changes in the selected countries
    v$selectedCountries <- input$country
    print(v$selectedCountries)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

- Click the `groupby` input.
- Add Country to the selected values
- Select multiple countries in the `country` input
- Delete Country from the `groupby` input
- The `country` input disappears
- Add Country to the `groupby` input
- The `country` input reappears, and the previously selected values are still selected.

Comment: I heard it several times now that a render function shall not be used inside a reactive. Do you know a source or do you have an explanation?

Comment: Theory:  reactives are functions, just like the renderXXXX functions.  Put them inside another function and their scope is no longer global and they are not available to the global server process that runs the app.  See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/understanding-reactivity.html) - and other articles in the series - for more information.  Practice: as you've discovered, it just doesn't work!  If my answer was useful, please accept it by clicking on the tick at top left.